# Is there a better way to use axios to get 2 API results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I'm creating a ReactJS application, and I have a problem: I'm getting results from 1 api, like bellow:

```
const perPage = 20;
const offset = (page * perPage) - perPage;
const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${perPage}&offset=${offset}`);
```

With the example above, I can return a lot of pokemons.

It returns to me a object with pokemon id and pokemon name. There's another API link, that brings a lot of another informations, like bellow:

```
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/PASS_HERE_POKEMON_ID
```

It brings only one result per time, but a lot of informations.

My question is: What do I do? Should I use the second API and make a loop (with I think is not the best situation), or there's a way to get 20 pokemons (for example), and pass the id of them in the second API, but using axios, promises or another best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach would be:

```js
const getPokemon = (id) => axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/${id}`);

const getPokemons = async (perPage, offset) => {
  const { pokemons } = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${perPage}&offset=${offset}`);
  Promise.all(pokemons.map(pok => getPokemon(pok.id)))
    then(results => {
      // array with the response of each call
});
```

More about `Promise.all` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Most HTTP APIs are rate limited in some way. Using the shown approach can be really problematic due to that. On the one hand it increases the risk of being blocked and makes it hard to recover in case you get a rate limit error back.

Comment: @t.niese [_Since the move to static hosting in November 2018, rate limiting has been removed entirely, but we still encourage you to limit the frequency of requests to limit our hosting costs._](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#fairuse)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The API itself has not rate limit in form of an account, but they still measure the number of requests per IP and time frame `It is also very popular. […] People not complying with the fair use policy will have their IP address permanently banned.`. They explicitly say that you should cache the results, and the client libraries they provide do that. `pokemons.map(pok => getPokemon(pok.id))` issues the requests in parallel, browsers usually limit them to around 2-6 per domain,  so there is might not be a problem there. But using that shown code in nodejs can become a problem.